# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask, exception-handler

Добрый день не могу исправить ошибку в intent'e в классе `AsyncTask_DB_Test`

[image: g]

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EnglishFragment EnglishFrag;
    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction Transactioner;
    JapaniseFragment JapFrag;
    ChineseFragment ChinaFrag;
    RussianFragment RussFrag;
    RecyclerView Words;
    ArrayList<Word> wordList;

    EditText wordEnglish;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EnglishFrag = new EnglishFragment();
        JapFrag = new JapaniseFragment();
        ChinaFrag = new ChineseFragment();
        RussFrag = new RussianFragment();
        Words = findViewById(R.id.Recycler);
        wordList = new ArrayList<>();

        wordEnglish = findViewById(R.id.wordEnglishMainActivity);
    }

    public void Find(View view) {

       Intent intentToFragments = new Intent(this, TranslateActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentToFragments);

        AsyncTask_DB_Test asyncTask_db_test = new AsyncTask_DB_Test();
        asyncTask_db_test.execute("Hat");
        String intentFromDB = getIntent().getStringExtra("Give");
        System.err.println(intentFromDB);

        wordList.add(new Word(wordEnglish.getText()));
        Words.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 1));
        Words.setAdapter(new WordAdapter(wordList));
    }
}
```

AsyncTask_DB_Test

```
class AsyncTask_DB_Test extends AsyncTask<String, String,String>{

    protected String wordEnglishText = "111";
    protected String defenitionEnglishText= "111";
    protected String wordRussianText = "111";
    protected String defenitionRussianText = "111";
    protected String wordChinaText = "111";
    protected String defenitionChinaText = "111";
    protected String wordJapanText = "111";
    protected String defenition_JapanText = "111";

    InputStream is = null;
    String result = null;
    String line = null;

    private  Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wordEnglish", strings\[0\]));

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://siteforproject.000webhostapp.com/get_products_details.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity enity = response.getEntity();
            is = enity.getContent();
            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        }


        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 100);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            reader.close();
            Log.e("pass 2", "connection" + result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
        }

        try {
            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            // wordEnglishText = (json_data.getString("wordEnglish"));
            defenitionEnglishText = (json_data.getString("defenitionEnglish"));
            wordRussianText = (json_data.getString("wordRussian"));
            defenitionRussianText = (json_data.getString("defenitionRussian"));
            wordChinaText = (json_data.getString("wordChina"));
            defenitionChinaText = (json_data.getString("defenitionChina"));
            wordJapanText = (json_data.getString("wordJapan"));
            defenition_JapanText = (json_data.getString("defenition_Japan"));
            Log.e("pass 3", defenitionEnglishText);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Intent intentToMainActivity = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intentToMainActivity.putExtra("Give",defenitionEnglishText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас `context` не проинициализирован.
Добавьте конструктор:

```
class AsyncTask_DB_Test extends AsyncTask<String, String,String>{

   private Context context;

   public AsyncTask_DB_Test(Context context){
      this.context = context;
   }
}
```

И создавайте как-то так:

```
AsyncTask_DB_Test asyncTask_db_test = new AsyncTask_DB_Test(this);
```